# Can Textile parse Flash like Youtube or Vimeo?

Tags: flash, textile

Is it possible to use Textile to parse a Flash file so that I can allow our website users to submit Youtube or Vimeo videos in marked-down format?

I couldn't see this on the Textile reference page but thought I'd ask here in case someone has found a way to do this.

http://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/